# Elasticsearch RAM issue on production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch 2.3.4 with searchkick  and MongoDB on production server. We are running our entire rails app on 2GB RAM aws. Elasticsearch is consuming RAM making the server go down. Please.. how do I solve this issue? Need help

This my elasticsearch.yml file

```
# ======================== Elasticsearch Configuration =========================
#
# NOTE: Elasticsearch comes with reasonable defaults for most settings.
#       Before you set out to tweak and tune the configuration, make sure you
#       understand what are you trying to accomplish and the consequences.
#
# The primary way of configuring a node is via this file. This template lists
# the most important settings you may want to configure for a production cluster.
#
# Please see the documentation for further information on configuration options:
# <http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-configuration.html>
#
# ---------------------------------- Cluster -----------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for your cluster:
#
 cluster.name: my-application
#
# ------------------------------------ Node ------------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for the node:
# 
 node.name: node-1
#
# Add custom attributes to the node:
#
# node.rack: r1
#
# ----------------------------------- Paths ------------------------------------
#
# Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
#
# path.data: /path/to/data
#
# Path to log files:
#
# path.logs: /path/to/logs
#
# ----------------------------------- Memory -----------------------------------
#
# Lock the memory on startup:
# bootstrap.mlockall: true
#
#
# Add custom attributes to the node:
#
# node.rack: r1
#
# ----------------------------------- Paths ------------------------------------
#
# Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
#
# path.data: /path/to/data
#
# Path to log files:
#
# path.logs: /path/to/logs
#
# ----------------------------------- Memory -----------------------------------
#
# Lock the memory on startup:
# bootstrap.mlockall: true
#
# Make sure that the `ES_HEAP_SIZE` environment variable is set to about half the memory
# available on the system and that the owner of the process is allowed to use this limit.
#
# Elasticsearch performs poorly when the system is swapping the memory.
#
# ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
#
# Set the bind address to a specific IP (IPv4 or IPv6):
#
# network.host: ********
#
# Set a custom port for HTTP:
#
# http.port: 9200
#
# For more information, see the documentation at:
# <http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html>
# --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------
#
# Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when new node is started:
# The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
#
#
# Elasticsearch performs poorly when the system is swapping the memory.
#
# ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
#
# Set the bind address to a specific IP (IPv4 or IPv6):
#
# network.host: *******
#
# Set a custom port for HTTP:
#
# http.port: 9200
#
# For more information, see the documentation at:
# <http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html>
# --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------
#
# Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when new node is started:
# The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
#
# discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["host1", "host2"]
# 
# Prevent the "split brain" by configuring the majority of nodes (total number of nodes / 2 + 1):
# 
# discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 3
# 
# For more information, see the documentation at:
# <http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-discovery.html>
#
# ---------------------------------- Gateway -----------------------------------

#
# Block initial recovery after a full cluster restart until N nodes are started:
#
# gateway.recover_after_nodes: 3
# 
# For more information, see the documentation at:
# <http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-gateway.html>
#
# ---------------------------------- Various -----------------------------------
#
# Disable starting multiple nodes on a single system:
#
# node.max_local_storage_nodes: 1
# Prevent the "split brain" by configuring the majority of nodes (total number of nodes / 2 + 1):
#
# discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 3
#
# For more information, see the documentation at:
# <http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-discovery.html>
#
# ---------------------------------- Gateway -----------------------------------
#
# Block initial recovery after a full cluster restart until N nodes are started:

#
# gateway.recover_after_nodes: 3
# 
# For more information, see the documentation at:
# <http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-gateway.html>
#
# ---------------------------------- Various -----------------------------------
#
# Disable starting multiple nodes on a single system:
#
# node.max_local_storage_nodes: 1
# 
# Require explicit names when deleting indices:
# 
# action.destructive_requires_name: true
```

Comment: Elasticsearch somewhere suggests configuring it with 8 gb fixed memory. If you don't have spatial stuff or a very big amount of data less works but 2 GB for all stuff seems a little low. How many documents are in your index?

Comment: Currently we have like 12000 docs. In future its gonna go huge!

Comment: "huge" is very subjective. if you have some million documents (with parent child thats easy to get). Configure the memory to like 4+ GB or so and see how it behaves. 2 GB for "huge" will not be enough.

Comment: Yea, like you said in millions. It works fine on a 6GB machine. Its the 2GB sever where I am getting the issue.

Comment: Read what they say under Memory in your yml. You can try to set the environment variable and give it 512MB as long as you have only 12000 docs. But don't expect it to have good performance.

Answer (score 1):

2 GB RAM is not enough to run all that. Separate the components across multiple instances vertically or scale the instance to a larger instance type with much more RAM.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean. It would help free up some RAM and also give you more flexibility and scalability in the future.